# not able to access NSSearchField using viewWithTag

Tags: macos, cocoa, tags, nssearchfield

I am creating the searchfield in my appcontroller.m class and adding it as subview to BrowserView in awakeFromNib

```
    mysearchField = [ [ NSSearchField alloc ] initWithFrame: NSMakeRect(10 , 50.0, 225.0, 35.0) ];

    [mysearchField setTag:2];

    [[mysearchField cell] setPlaceholderString:@"Page Number & Press Enter"];
    [BrowserView addSubview: mysearchField ];

    [mysearchField release];


-(NSView *)fullBrowserView
{
    NSLog(@"fullBrowserView called");
    return fullBrowserView;
}
```

When I am trying to accessing this searchfield from a different nsview sub class

```
-(BOOL)becomeFirstResponder {

    appController *pAppController = [[appController alloc] init];
    //[pIKBController testMethod];
    NSSearchField *mySearchFieldTemp =(NSSearchField *) [[pAppController fullBrowserView]  viewWithTag:2];
    [mySearchFieldTemp setStringValue:@""];

    [pAppController release];
    return [super becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

fullBrowserView is getting called with [pAppController fullBrowserView],but my NSSearchField is not resetting to nil value.

Note : fullBrowserView is IBOutlet and created in the Xib file(Interface Builder)

What might be the problem.Please help.